# MySQL/PHP: Insert form array into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, forms

I am a PHP newbie having a problem inserting an array from a form into the database using foreach statement. 
I am trying to create a form that accepts Score, Grade and Comment for each subject. However,only the last subject gets inserted into the database. The list of subjects is loaded from previously registered subjects (I have no problem with that). My problem is getting all the subjects to save back to database.
This is the form i use:

```
<legend>ENTER RESULTS:</legend>
<input type="hidden" name="results[]" value= "<?php foreach ($subjects as $subject):?>
<ul>
<li> <input type="text" name="subject_name" size="10" value ="<?php htmlout($subject['subject_name']); ?>"/>
          </label>
     <label for="subject_score">SCORE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_score" size="5" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_score);?>"/> <label for="subject_score">GRADE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_grade" size="5" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_grade);?>"/><label for="subject_grade">COMMENT:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_comment" size="30" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_comment);?>"/> </div></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php
        htmlout($student_id); ?>
  </fieldset>
```

This is the php code i use:

```
if (isset($_GET['result']))
{
try
{
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO results SET
      student_id = :student_id,
      subject_name = :subject_name,
      subject_grade = :subject_score,
      subject_grade = :subject_grade,
      subject_comment = :subject_comment';
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  foreach ($_POST['results'] as $result)
  {
  $s->bindValue(':student_id',$_POST['student_id']);
  $s->bindValue(':subject_name', $_POST['subject_name']);
  $s->bindValue(':subject_score', $_POST['subject_score']);
  $s->bindValue(':subject_grade', $_POST['subject_grade']);
  $s->bindValue(':subject_comment', $_POST['subject_comment']);
  $s->execute();
  }
  }
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Could not Register the Student for the Subjects, Please try again'.$e->GetMessage();
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}
echo 'Success';
```

Comment: This code makes no attempt to write any data to any database. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thanks, omitted the PHP code i use, edited.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="results[]" value= "<?php foreach ($subjects as $subject):?> has error

Comment: @timus2001 thanks, removed that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  form element in array like **subject_score[]**

your form should be like

```
foreach
<input type="text" name="subject_name[]" size="10" value ="<?php htmlout($subject['subject_name']); ?>"/>
          </label>
     <label for="subject_score">SCORE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_score[]" size="5" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_score);?>"/> <label for="subject_score">GRADE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_grade[]" size="5" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_grade);?>"/><label for="subject_grade">COMMENT:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_comment[]" size="30" value = "<?php
        htmlout($subject_comment);?>"/> </div></li>
endforeach
```

then you can collect those value like below

```
foreach($_POST['subject_name'] as $key=>$val){
  //val will hold subject name
}
```